# Getting Errorno-EACCES error while installing Rails on ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ubuntu

I successfully installed ruby on my Ubuntu server by using the following command.

```
1-sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
2-sudo apt-add-repository ppa:brightbox/ruby-ng
3-sudo apt-get update
4-sudo apt-get install ruby2.1
```

But when i tried to install Rails version 4.2.0 using the below command.

```
gem install rails --version=4.2.0
```

i got the following error.

> Error:

```
Error:While executing gem (Errorno-EACCES)
permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /var/lib/gems
```

Please help me to resolve this error and install rails successfully.I also have another doubt here.After installing ruby when i chcked the version it is showing me the ruby version 2.1.7 but here i need ruby version 2.1.5.Please also help me do this.I am using Ubuntu 14.0 version.

Comment: Did you try sudoing.  `sudo gem install rails --version=4.2.0`

Comment: @vjdhama:yes i did that the above error has gone bot one new error after some installation `Errror: Error installing rails Error: failed to build gem native extension`.

Comment: Did you get the answer? Accept the answer if you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue might be because the `gem` executable is not installed in user directory.

You can confirm this using `which gem`.

Run this command for installing rails.

```
sudo gem install rails --version=4.2.0
```

**UPDATE**:

The error : `Errror: Error installing rails Error: failed to build gem native extension` might be because of lack of dev-headers.

Try running this :

```
sudo apt-get install ruby2.1-dev
```

These errors are the reasons you should probably try using [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) or [rvm](https://rvm.io/) to install ruby and rails.